# Remove duplicate rows of data

Tags: powershell

Remove duplicate rows of data leaving one record with the fastest time

my data looks like this:

```
First Name Last Name    Fastest Time     Time To Cut
---------- ---------    --------         -----------
Jack       Black        01:31.00         33.497 should be removed    
Jeff       Black        01:27.22         29.718     
Mike       Fair         01:01.33         3.823  should be removed     
Mike       Fair         00:58.12         0.621      
Anthony    Gal          01:04.36         6.858      
Steff      Hart         01:06.50         8.999      
Steff      Hart         01:07.50         9.999  should be removed
```

I am trying to get the fastest time for each person in the table.  I have tried using `Select-Object -Unique` (with the table sorted on '`Last Name`','`First Name'`) but I can't figure out what to do from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the data by name, then select the best time from each group:

```bsh
$data |Group-Object 'Last Name','First Name' |ForEach-Object {
    # Output only the fastest time from each group
    $_.Group |Sort-Object 'Fastest Time' |Select -First 1
}
```